# How to send get request with a body?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, axios, backdrop

I am trying to send a get request to my API to get a list of users. But I need there is an exclude list that the response must exclude. How can I send this exclude list in my GET request?

Comment: Are you sending the request from a browser or Node.JS?

Answer (score 1):

You can send a body with the request. Query parameters is probably the best way to do it though. The folks at [Elastic.co say](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_empty_search.html):

> The truth is that RFC 7231—the RFC that deals with HTTP semantics and
> content—​does not define what should happen to a GET request with a
> body! As a result, some HTTP servers allow it, and some—​especially
> caching proxies—​don’t.
>
> The authors of Elasticsearch prefer using GET for a search request
> because they feel that it describes the action—​retrieving
> information—​better than the POST verb. However, because GET with a
> request body is not universally supported, the search API also accepts
> POST requests:

Answer (score -1):

You cannot send a request body when making a GET request. However, you can add it as a [query parameter](https://branch.io/glossary/query-parameters/). Alternatively, you can make a POST request.

Comment: The answer doens't related to the problem.